# Ansible: Use filter as conditional in playbook for role-inclusion

Tags: filter, ansible, conditional-statements, version, jinja2

We have a couple of roles that we want to be executed in a Playbook dependent on a version condition. Since this role is used in many Playbooks, it doesn't seem right to do the conditional check in the role itself, as it will lead to details leaking in to the role.

What we want to do:

```
    - name: Provisioninging for Windows Appservers
       hosts: WindowsAppservers
       roles:
       - { role: DotNet471, when: arenaVersion is version('18.1','>=', strict=False)  }
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'arenaVersion is version('18.1'' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '}', expected ')'. String: {% if arenaVersion is version('18.1' %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/mnt/c/Code/Git/AnsiblePlaybooks/roles/DotNet471/tasks/main.yaml': line 1, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - name: Install DotNet Framework 4.7.1\n     ^ here\n"}
```

It seems like the `,` sign in the [version filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison) is parsed incorrectly?

Comparing on string works fine, like so:

```
- { role: VCRedist140, when: arenaVersion|string() ==  "17.2" }
```

My version of Ansible is `2.6.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use unquoted YAML strings, so `when:` string is terminated with the following `,`.

Quote full `when` statement:

```
- { role: DotNet471, when: "arenaVersion is version('18.1','>=', strict=False)" }
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I knew it had to be as simple as that.